# how to make to make the div to take 100% of rest of the space?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created a sidebar and I don't want the sidebar to take more than `height:100vh` of the canvas as you can see there is info data after the image so if the data is way more then it overflows and makes the sidebar above 100vh which I don't want.
So what I want is if the data is more and it is making the sidebar go above 100vh then the info data section becomes scrollable with `overflow: scroll` (as it is currently now) in case it doesn't overflow and goes on a big screen then the `overflow: scroll` does not have to work and the empty scroll bar has to disappear

```css
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  font-family: arial;
}
img{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  object-fit:cover;
  border-radius:500px
   
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  height:100vh;
  padding:20px 10px;
}

.info{
  height:500px;
  overflow:scroll
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="some-stuff">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/13538314/pexels-photo-13538314.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600&lazy=load" alt="">
    <hr>

  </div>

<!--   info Data -->
      <h2>info Data section</h2>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="stud-dta-container">
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Email Address:</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">youremail@email.com </p>
      </div>
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">00 0000 0000 000</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>
        <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question

Comment: I dont know maybe you want this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content

Comment: @Error2.0 `fit-content` still doesn't have a good [cross-browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content#browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there, some tweaks that we'll make should get you on the right track.

- First things first, a good practice is to use the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property that *"sets how the total width and height of an element is calculated"* <sup>(source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing))</sup> which has a very handy value, `border-box` that *"tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height"* <sup>(source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#border-box))</sup> which will allow your `div.container` to **NOT** exceed `100vh` even with the set padding.
- And now to make the info section (`div.info`) take the rest of the space and optionally, or rather automatically, adds vertical scrollbars when needed we will, thanks to the `display: flex` set on `div.info`'s parent (`div.container`), apply a [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) of `1` that will allow `div.info` to take the remaining vertical space (thanks to `flex-direction: column` set on `div.container`), without exceeding the `100vh` height on the parent.
- And finally, we'll use [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) set to `auto` on `div.info` that will allow that element to have a vertical scroll when needed without exceeding the parent's explicitly set `100vh` value.

Here's a live demo of what's being said:

```css
/** apply the border-box for the box-sizing property (always set it glabally so all the elemnts inherit that value for better calculations and layout behaviour predectibility) */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 500px
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  /** thanks to the above box-sizing rule, the padding will be substructed from the height and width of the elemnt thus the element's height won't exceed 100vh */
}

.info {
  /** removed the explicitly set height as flex-grow will do the trick for us */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /** allow scrolling when needed */
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="some-stuff">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/13538314/pexels-photo-13538314.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600&lazy=load" alt="">
    <hr>
  </div>
  <!--   info Data -->
  <h2>info Data section</h2>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="stud-dta-container">
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Email Address:</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">youremail@email.com </p>
      </div>
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">00 0000 0000 000</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> I recommend moving the `h2` element and put it inside the `div.info` for a better result when the screen is too small (like the snippet's result section here on SO).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Thabet! I truly appreciate the time and effort you have put into it
Thanks, Thabet Again!

Comment: @ShayanKanwal You're welcome! That's why we're here actually to assist each other. Glad I managed to land some help.

Answer (score 1):

With flex, you can use flex-grow(flex-shrink & flex-basis), the browser will do the calculation for you. Then only the parent is to be sized. Here you set an height to 100vh, but also add a padding. To include the padding, you need to reset the the box-sizing propertie.

Finally, a reset on box-sizing on the flex parent , keeps in the viewport, then , info are to be told to grow (as much avalaible space) and overflow if that is not enough.

possible CSS fix:

```css
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  font-family: arial;
}
img{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  object-fit:cover;
  border-radius:500px
   
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  height:100vh;
  padding:20px 10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.info{
  flex-grow:1;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="some-stuff">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/13538314/pexels-photo-13538314.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600&lazy=load" alt="">
    <hr>

  </div>

<!--   info Data -->
      <h2>info Data section</h2>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="stud-dta-container">
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Email Address:</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">youremail@email.com </p>
      </div>
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">00 0000 0000 000</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>

      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>
        <div class="stud-dta bd-btm-ext-grey mt-2">
        <span class="fs-7">Test::</span>
        <p class="mt-1 fs-6-6 mb-2">Test Data</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to slightly rearrange html content (in order to have your  tag inside the info section) like this:

```
<div class="info">
  <h2>info Data section</h2>
  <div class="stud-dta-container">
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Then you only need to use a known-height "some-suff" div and set the heights of the other divs:

```
.container{
  display: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px 10px; /*** verical-padding = 20px ***/
  height: calc(100vh - 40px); /*** 40px = 2*verical-padding ***/
  top: 0;
}
.some-stuff { height:160px; }
.info {
  height:calc(100% - 160px);
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/3Lyz1wut/